# Changing the ID of a new object in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have a Customer model in my Rails app and whenever a new customer is created I am getting a number as input from the user and I want that number to become the id of the customer on my database instead of the default 1, 2, 3, and so on. Is it possible to do that? If so, how?

EDIT: Let me be a more clear about what I want: I have a Customer and A Brand model. A customer has_many brands and a brand belongs_to a customer. Whenever the user creates a new brand, I want to connect it to its customer using that number that the user entered for the customer. Right now, whenever the user creates a new brand, I ask him to enter the customer_id value to connect the brand to a customer, but that is the id number generated by Rails. How do I make that customer_id attribute refer to the specific number the user entered for a customer, instead of the customer id generated by Rails.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, but don't do that. Just allow Rails to manage the auto-generated ID itself, and add this number - whatever it is - as a separate attribute in your model and saved to a separate field in your database.

Comment: ^ this... Save yourself a headache and let Rails do its thing :)

Comment: But I want to be able to refer to a customer based on that number, not the id number generated by Rails. Is there any way I can do that? Sorry, I'm new to Rails.

Comment: Yes you can @MPorto.  Just include an attribute like `customer_id` in your model/migration.

Comment: Better to use a field/attribute name that people **won't** confuse with a conventional Rails foreign key, like `code` or `number`. You might also want to look at something like the [obfuscate_id](https://github.com/namick/obfuscate_id) gem which provides a predictable code from your `id` without storing anything different.

Answer (score 0):

As smathy mentioned, you can do the following:

1.First, generate a migration that add your custom attribute

```
rails g migration AddCustomerIdToCustomers customer_id:integer
```

2.When user enter the id, you would want to do something like this:

```
@customer.customer_id=params[:customer_id]
@customer.save
```

3.Then you can retrieve the custom object as

```
@customer = Customer.find_by_customer_id(customer_id)
```

where customer_id is the id you want.

As the above answer suggests, it is better let Rails handle the id attribute, because it is used extensively in Rails to handle database relationships ActiveRecord queries, etc. You do not want the extra headache of modifying it yourself.